# I got only 1 Item in list view

Tags: android, listview, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to use ConstraintLayout and I am making simple listview. But the problem in the list view is it is not scrolling So I tried to put scroll view as parent and I put ListView inside it but I got only 1 item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup">

        <RadioButton
            android:text="To Ferenhite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ctof"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:text="To Celcius"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ftoc"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn_convert"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioGroup" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="329dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_convert"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/list_temperature" />
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I tried to make an UI in lenier layout and then convert it but it doesn't work for me. All components were disturbed. I can remove scrollview and only put the ListView too but it doesn't work. Please help me with that. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can't (shouldn't) have a listview inside a scrollview.

Comment: I know that but only list view is not scrolling that why I tried.

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to assign an Adapter to the ListView. How are you adding items to the ListView?
Post Adapter class if you are using one.

Comment: He said he got 1 item, that could possibly mean that he has an Adapter.